# Is git unpack-objects of any use?

Tags: git-commit, git

I don't understand what is the need/use of the `git unpack-objects` command.
If I have a pack file *outside* of my repository and run the `git unpack-objects` on it the pack file will be "decompressed" and all the object files will be placed in `.git/objects`. But what is the need for this? If I just place the pack and index files in `.git/objects` I can still see all the commits and have a functional repo and have *less* space occupied by my .git since the pack file is compact.
So why would anyone need to run this command?

Comment: It's a plumbing command, and those are for: maintenance, debug, writing new things no one has thought much about before, etc.  Usually the order would be "writing things, then maintenance, then debug" but in this case I suspect "debug" goes first.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know, ask the downvoter...

Answer (score 0):

Pack file uses the format that is used with normal transfer over the network. So, I can think of two main reasons to use the manual command instead of network:

1. having a similar update workflow in an environment without network configuration between the machines or where that cannot be used for other reasons
2. debugging/inspecting the contents of the transfer

For 1), you could just use a disk or any kind of mobile media for your files. It could be encrypted, for instance.